# Nonhomogeneous Systems of m equations in n unknowns and Solution Spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My book says that solutions sets of nonhomogeneous systems of $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns is NEVER a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.
Why? If we look at any two planes intersecting in $\Bbb R^3$, there may be a line formed. This line DOES have the $0$ vector (a single point on the line), is closed under addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

No, the line of intersection does not contain the origin.  If the system $A{\bf x}={\bf b}$ is nonhomogeneous, this means by definition that ${\bf b}\ne0$.  Therefore ${\bf x}=0$ is not a solution.

Comment: I don't really understand the concept of a subspace anymore. I thought we were supposed to look at if THE VECTOR 0 is contained in the line, not the coordinate point. I thought a subspace is a set of vectors... I'm confused.

Comment: The line is a line... It should contain the vector 0, a 0-dimensional vector.

Comment: A line is a set of points, not a set of vectors.  A point can be "interpreted" as a vector, in which case it is the vector from the origin to the point.  So saying that the vector $\bf0$ lies on the line is the same as saying the point $\bf0$ is on the line.  See if [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645672) is helpful.