# Norm of an $n$-tuple

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Let’s say we have some $n$-tuple $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Could we take its $\mathscr{l}^2$ norm? I mean what’s the difference between a vector and a tuple anyway? Well, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645672/what-is-the-difference-between-a-point-and-a-vector) led me to believe that the $\mathscr{l}^2$ norm is not defined for tuples. However, my friend insists that it does exist and that is similarly defined as 
$$
\|x\|=\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^{1/2}.
$$
But, aren’t tuples and vectors basically the same thing? Of course, one represents displacement relative to zero and the other a fixed point, but in this context, are they the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A realization came over me - coordinate vectors are not the same thing as vectors: a vector is an element of a vector space where as a coordinate vector is a linear combination of basis vectors.