# Is a point on plane, scalar or vector?

Tags: vectors

I got little confused about the following thing when I was revisiting vector. Suppose we have set up a two dimensional co-ordinate system. Then when I simply say point (1,1), then it's simply a point ( something like scalar thing). But when I am drawing an arrow from origin to that point, it is vector now. The same thing when we changed our way of looking has turned from similar-to-scalar to a vector. Somehow, I think
I have understood it incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: Both of these are graphic representations of mathematical objects. A vector is an element of a vector space — nothing more and nothing less. So a point $(1,1)$ can be interpreted as a vector in the vector space $\Bbb R^2$ or as a point in the plane $\Bbb R^2$. It's a matter of perspective.

Comment: Some [previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645672/what-is-the-difference-between-a-point-and-a-vector)